# Is it possible to make a command-line alias for `!!`?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I have a somewhat idiosyncratic CLI workflow, but it works for me. I commonly iterate on commands and then use the result of those commands in the next command. For example:

Finding a file:

```
$ ff thing_im_looking_for_spec
./specs/foo/bar/thing_im_looking_for_spec.rb
```

Re-running that command (since it's fast) and using it's result as an argument to another program:

```
$ rspec `!!`
```

...which expands to:

```
$ rspec `ff thing_im_looking_for_spec`
```

...and runs the test I'm looking for. From there I can press the up arrow and make a quick edit to:

```
$ vim `ff thing_im_looking_for_spec`
```

...to edit that file.

I know it's weird, but it works great. It's very comfortable for me to use [backtick][bang][bang][backtick] to mean "yeah, that thing."

But "`!!`" is just a wee bit hard to type. Is it possible to make an alias for it? I've had trouble figuring out how to do this because "`!!`" is itself an alias for the last command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `!!` itself can be wrapped in an alias or a function by using `history -p`, which allows scripts to get the result of any !expansion (even if the whole feature is disabled):

```
alias 1='eval "$(history -p !!)"'
```

Now it's `` vim `1` `` or `` rspec `1` ``, which is relatively more convenient to type (no need for Shift). Can't do much about the backticks, however.

---

Well, technically you can achieve this without backticks, but it involves weird tricks:

```
shopt -s extdebug
trap 'case $BASH_COMMAND in *" that")
          eval "${BASH_COMMAND/%" that"/" $(eval "$(history -p !!)")"}";
          false;
      esac' DEBUG
```

Now it's `vim that` or `rspec that`. (This example only detects the *last* word, to limit the explosion risk. Modifying to match/replace words anywhere in the command line is left as an exercise.)

---

One less weird trick is to bind a *keypress* (macro) that automatically inserts `` `!!` `` as if typed:

```
bind '"\e[2~": "`!!`"'
```

This example tells bash's *readline* to translate `\e[2~` (which is actually the <kbd>Insert</kbd> key) to `` `!!` ``, so you can type `vim Insert` to obtain `` vim `!!` ``. Any input, not necessarily a special key sequence, can be turned into a macro.

(Among other possible convenient keys, Alt+Enter is `\e\n`, Ctrl+F is `\C-f`, and so on.)

Comment: Wow, this is so cool. Binding [Insert] seems to strike the nicest balance between convenient vs. crazy. Thank you.